# I deleted the faces on the other side of a model, how can bring them back?

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, edges, shortcut

So I made a model but then I deleted the faces on the other side of the model by accident, I did it a while ago so I can't redo the action. Is there anyway I can bring them back with the vertices, edges, and faces?

[image: The model]

Comment: what faces have you deleted? you have disable all the axis in your Mirror modifier, maybe enable Y as it looks like you're supposed to mirror your object on Y?

Comment: Agreed - re-check the Y-box in the modifier panel on the right.

Comment: use mirror modifier and set direction to copy other side